# Get the current response onSubmit

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there any way to find out the current response of the Google Form (programmatically)?

In the `onSubmit` function.

Looked over [their documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getResponse%28String%29) but I have to provide the `respondId`.

How do I find the `respondId`?

A snipped code from them about this is:

```
// Open a form by ID and log the responses to each question.
 var form = FormApp.openById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
 var formResponses = form.getResponses();
 for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
   var formResponse = formResponses[i];
   var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
   for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
     var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
     Logger.log('Response #%s to the question "%s" was "%s"',
         (i + 1).toString(),
         itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(),
         itemResponse.getResponse());
   }
 }
```

UPDATE:

```
function onSubmit(e) {
  /* Get values entered by filling the form */
  var itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  var myWantedValue = itemResponses[COLUMN_NUMBER].getResponse();
}
```

Note: **By passing the e(vent) as parameter the values can be accessed by submitting the live form, NOT by the script editor!**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This code gives you the values for the last form response, is that what you're looking for ?

```
function myFunction() {
  var formResponses = FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses();
  Logger.log(formResponses.length);
  var formResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length-1];
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
  for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
    Logger.log('Last response to the question "%s" was "%s"',
               itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(),
               itemResponse.getResponse());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have updated my question, managed to find a solution for my need. Your answer can be an alternative to my problem. +1!

Comment: Thanks ! Both ways are indeed returning the same result , I came to this one because I wanted to use your initial approach :-)

Comment: @Sergeinsas I am getting null for itemResponse.getScore(). I am using the same script. help me out.

Comment: please do not ask questions in comments, if you have a new issue then ask a new question and include the code you are using.

Comment: Doesn't this solution induce a race condition if someone else happens to submit the form at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read the exact response that triggered the execution of onSubmit(), to run another process on particular data, such as sending a confirmation email.

If the above is correct:

Instead of using the form as a data source for your later processing, try to read the Google Sheet storing the responses. It may seem the problem is the same: reading either data source (the form itself, or the sheet storing the data), doesn't point you to the exact entry that has triggered the onSubmit() event.

The difference is that in a sheet you can create a "reply_sent" column, to timestamp the instant each form response has been postprocessed, for example, having sent an automated reply based on its contents.

Then, when onSubmit() is run, it goes through all responses and processes not only the last one received, or the one having triggered the onSubmit() funtion, but also any other response that may have been left unreplied for whatever reason ("reply_sent" field blank). A last benefit from this approach is that your script is logging how it is behaving, since a date is recorded along with each response as it triggers obSubmit().

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set up a [custom confirmation message for each user](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner&groupby=&sort=&id=3507#makechanges).