# Event Object not working in google app script for onSubmit trigger in google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I created a google form and added a trigger which triggers whenever the form submit event is triggered. I need to use the event object for this event and when I add any line of code which tries to access this event then, an error occurs.

```
function onSubmit(e) {
  var s = e.values[0];
  Logger.log(s);
}
```

I get this error message when the function is triggered:

```
Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code")
```

My form has one text input field (basically its just a form where I'm testing and trying out things with Google App Script), so I'm trying to access the data in this field when the form is submitted.

Comment: could you add a line in your `onSubmit` function like this : `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));`  and see what is in the Logger ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the ActiveForm object instead of the event object.

```
function onSubmit() {

  var responses = FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses();
  var length = responses.length;
  var lastResponse = responses[length-1];
  var formValues = lastResponse.getItemResponses();

  Logger.log(formValues[0].getResponse());
}
```

This code does basically what you need (after you set up the trigger like you did).

Better explanation can be found here: [google script get the current response onSubmit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647764/google-script-get-the-current-response-onsubmit)

Comment: I found out what was wrong, thanks to the code you submitted :). Thanks.
What happened was that the event object contained a FormResponse object as a member. I cannot access e.value[0] as it is. I have to access the FormResponse object and so on. The event object contained
`{response=FormResponse, source=Form, triggerUid=some no., authMode=FULL}`

Comment: @piscator got it right.. thank you so much man.. this was so frustrating.. I have at least 3 forms implemented in which I can access responses from the e.NamedValues  with code tied to the spreadhsheet but for some extrange reason it wouldn't work on the last form I needed to implement. I can't tell you how greateful I am. cheerts.

Comment: Great to hear this @FranciscoCortes! Good to know this still works.