# Google Apps Script my installed onFormSubmit trigger is not returning source object in the event object

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, form-submit

So, I programmatically install a onFormSubmit trigger:

```
formTrigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("respondToFormSubmit").forForm(form).onFormSubmit().create();
```

When I submit the form I receive an event object but it only contains the response, Authmode, and triggerUid properties. There is no source property. What am I doing wrong?

onSubmitCode:

```
function respondToFormSubmit(e) {
    Logger.log("respondToFormSubmit() is a go...");
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e).forEach(
    function (val) {
        Logger.log("e property = " + val);
    });
```

}

results:

```
[17-05-11 10:45:45:445 EDT] respondToFormSubmit() is a go...
[17-05-11 10:45:45:446 EDT] e property = response
[17-05-11 10:45:45:447 EDT] e property = authMode
[17-05-11 10:45:45:448 EDT] e property = triggerUid
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is this a standalone script? Container bound script for a form, a spreadsheet?

Comment: This is a stand alone script for a form.

Comment: Since this is a standalone script it does not have a form source i.e. script doesn't belong to a form. [The documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_3) doesn't say it outright, but that is what is gather from it. I am assuming you are trying to have a common trigger for multiple forms and determine the which form triggered the script?

Comment: My initial assignment binds it to a form. The form is valid and I have successfully triggered the function when submitting that form.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647764/google-script-get-the-current-response-onsubmit