# get live answer of the google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Im making a form using google apps script, that requires students name and ID, but some students just have submitted fake names or IDs or both!
so I really need to
1- check their answers at the same time of responding (dynamic form)
or
2- checking the answers after submission

no idea about the 1st approach!

but the 2nd one has a problem, if more than 1 student is submitting at the same time, I cant go to responses spreadsheet and see if the last respond is fake or not, cuz the last one could be the answer of the 2nd student.

I have searched everywhere but nothing works
not even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647764/get-the-current-response-onsubmit)

any idea?
thanks

## update

at least I made a onsubmit trigger, collecting emails and studentsId.
then validate the answers, if they were true, a link to another form will be sent to them, and if not it will notify them!
from what I read in this days, the only way to get live answers is to write a HTML page to react to every response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should `Collect email addresses` be save enough to ensure it is not a fake submit?

---

What do you mean by 'check' in 1?

Do you mean validation of answer?

If yes, you could do it with either HTML or JS

**HTML (validation of `input`):**

HTML attributes `type`, `required`, `pattern`, `maxlength`, `minlength`, `max`, `min`, `step`

i.e. `<input name="age" type="number" min="9" max="12">`

---

**JS (validation of `formData`):**

```js
$('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var values = {};
  $.each($('#myForm').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
    values[field.name] = field.value;
  });
  if (values['age'] < 10 || values['age'] >12) { return; }
  $(this).submit();
})
```

Comment: Yes I mean validation
There is a spreadsheet of students information

Comment: Why don't you set validation to `input` and/or `onsubmit`?

Comment: do you have links to explain more about these? I'm new to app script 

Comment: No, you should explain more. Please add the code of your form to the question. Also, please reply whether my answer `Collect email addresses` is solving your 'fake response' problem.

Comment: Anyway, I added examples to my answer.

Comment: hi again! 
thanks for your code and the time that you put on this!
at last I do something like that too, an the Idea comes from your code.
Thanks a lot